# In Github PR when after approval it shows Branch is out of date, if I ran following commands, does it remove previous approvals?

Tags: github, merge

So you know it's common in team where multiple people are working on same project. Now when you have done your work and you push it to Github, it triggers the approval process.

Before your commit gets approved, if someone else also pushed changes and his commit (if) got approved earlier, then Git will say your branch is out of date & you will need rebase it.

Now if someoe else had already approved and you were waiting for merge, but due to in-between commit you have to ask for approval again, is there a way to fix it?
Although that commit didn't conflict any of your files.

Comment: I also find this process quite annoying, not sure if there is a better way for it.